# Extract Databricks Cluster dependencies and add them in build.sbt to build jar in Azure DevOps

Tags: scala, build, jar, sbt, azure-databricks

I'm building a DevOps CICD pipeline that require me to: 
1. Detect and extract automatically all the dependencies in a Databricks Cluster 
2. Insert them automatically in the already existed build.sbt located in Azure Repos 
3. Build pipeline there to build the jar

I'm currently blocked in step 1 and 2. I have looked into plugins. but I'm not sure if it's the right direction. Or should I look into automation? It would be great if anyone can point me to the right direciton.

Everything has to be done on Azure plateform. So, no IntelliJ. Only bash command I guess?

Comment: Hi, for step one and step two, could it succeed locally with command-line tool?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT sorry for the late reply. I didn't see your message. The goal is to do everything in the platform. so, for example, if someone imports a spark lib in the Databricks notebook, I would have to dectect it automatically and insert it into the build.sbt, which is located in the Azure Repos, as "libraryDependencies += ......"
I am actually not familiar w/ Scala. I hope it's clear.

What I had been trying wasn't the right direction. I tried to extract the librairies in the cluster, which is in the format of jar, egg, whl, etc... And I just realised that that wasn't the right approach

Comment: In my opinion, what you want can't be done in azure devops pipeline unless it can be done in local commands by cmd or powershell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many solutions without success. I finally do it by writing a script (on python or bash). The goal is to put the scripts in the Azure DevOps pipeline to make everything automatic.